# parse data when url does not change (pagination)

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, parsing, web-scraping

i am interested in parsing data from [here](https://markets.ft.com/data/world/economic-calendar). However, other than the default page, I cannot `parse` either the `older` or `newer` data since there is no change in `url` address. How do i go about getting data other than that on the default page? I have been trying for long to find a solution, would really really appreciate any help. I am using `python 3.6` with `lxml` and `requests` for parsing `urls`

Comment: Look at the chrome console under the `Network` tab and click `older` or `newer` and watch what requests are made. It might help?

Comment: When ever you click Newer its been called this URL, Change rowId every time when you need new data 

https://markets.ft.com/data/world/ajax/getnextecoevents?rowId=79501&scrollForward=true&filter=%7B%22keyword%22%3A%22%22%2C%22impact%22%3A%22%22%2C%22countries%22%3A%5B%5D%7D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How that website works:**

When the page first loads, it loads with the current data inside the HTML. Any time you click `older` or `newer` in the pagination, it makes a `GET` request to this url:

```
https://markets.ft.com/data/world/ajax/getnextecoevents?rowId=79519&scrollForward=true&filter=%7B%22keyword%22%3A%22%22%2C%22impact%22%3A%22%22%2C%22countries%22%3A%5B%5D%7D`
```

Note the URL parameters:

```
rowId, scrollForward, filter
```

**Solution:**

Make custom requests to the URL above but simply decrement or increment the `rowId` parameter to scroll through the pages.

For example:

```
GET https://markets.ft.com/data/world/ajax/getnextecoevents?rowId=79519
GET https://markets.ft.com/data/world/ajax/getnextecoevents?rowId=79520
GET https://markets.ft.com/data/world/ajax/getnextecoevents?rowId=79521
```

Comment: great! thanks a lot. Can you share with me, where exactly did you find this url address. I took a look under the network tab (under inspect elements), but I can't find it

Comment: Yeah sure. Watch the network tab and press `older` or `newer` to trigger the GET request. It should show up under the `XHR` filter (or just filter `All`).

Comment: Just one last help, l tried the above solution on this website 'https://www.mutualfundindia.com/MF/return/TopFunds' but in this case the url address under XHR does not load the next page

Comment: I'm getting `Error. An error occurred while processing your request.` when I go to that link.

Answer (score 2):

Based on viewing the dev tools network requests, you can see that when you select a new date on the default page, the following GET request is made:

Base URL:

```
https://markets.ft.com/data/world/ajax/getnextecoevents?
```

query parameters (you will have to urlencode the filter dict)

```
startDate=2017-09-04&filter={"keyword":"","impact":"","countries":[]}
```

So, just make a request for whatever date you need, and use urllib to urlencode the remaining filter parameters.  This should get you what you need.